# bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function

Tags: peerjs

When I run `peerjs`, I get this error.

> "bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function"

I found the wrong code in the following:

```
const Peer = require('peerjs');
const Uid = require('uid');
const $ = require('jquery');


const config = {host: 'quydi2406.herokuapp.com', port: 443, secure: true, key:'peerjs'}

function getPeer(){
const id = Uid(10);
$('#peer-id').append(id);
return id;
}


 const peer =Peer(getPeer(), config);
 console.log(peer);
```

It `Peer()` unkwom

Comment: Is your question left incomplete ? What does `It Peer() unkwom` mean?

Comment: console shows errors like this:
Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1

Comment: I think function Peer() error